# How to add another condition to an expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp = i => i<15 && i>10;
```

I want to add a condition to `exp` after this line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply with this:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp = i => i < 15 && i > 10;
var compiled = exp.Compile();
exp = i => compiled(i) && i % 2 == 0;  //example additional condition
```

Note that you can't do it like this:

<strike>`exp = i => exp.Compile()(i) && i % 2 == 0;  //example additional condition`</strike>

because `exp` will be added to the closure by reference and as a result, calling it will cause a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: This will not work if you are using Linq-to-sql (like EntityFramework)

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow No compiled lambda will ever work with SQL wrappers, as they cannot parse compiled expressions into SQL. In this case you can just append subsequent `.Where` clauses to a deferred `IQueryable` object - much simpler than this.

Comment: Even though it is `IQueryable`, I just now executed it with EF `DbSet` properly : `exp = x => compiled(x) && !x.IsActive; return await _dbSet.CountAsync(exp);`

Answer (score 8):

You have two options. The first one is the version of BartoszKP, to blackbox the first expression and use it afterwards. However, while this has a great syntax support, it also means that systems like the Entity Framework cannot really use the expression, because it is blackboxed. If this expression was used in a database query, the EF could not check this predicate on the server, but has to retrieve all the data to the client, if it works at all.

Thus, if you want to use the expression e.g. for a database query, you have to use the Expression API, i.e.

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exp = i => i<15 && i>10;
exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(exp.Body, ...), exp.Parameters[0]);
```

The three dots indicate the expression that you want to insert as second part. You could use another expression created by the compiler, but you would then have to replace the parameters.

Comment: This won't work: [ideone](https://ideone.com/evRXwk). On Windows it throws `InvalidOperationException: variable 'i' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`.

Comment: @BartoszKP It does if you had threated your parameters carefully. Afaik, you have to use the same parameter, not just a parameter with the same name.

Comment: Perhaps you could add usage example to your answer. As it stands now it seems unclear how to make it work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use multiple `Where()` clauses to combine expressions in EF?

Comment: @oderibas for my case "where()" is boxed within another function, I just send and have access to the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from https://entityframework.net/ for .Net Framework 6.0

which also worked for me with .net core

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprA = a => a == 3;
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprB = b => b == 4;
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprC =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
                Expression.OrElse(
                    exprA.Body,
                    new ExpressionParameterReplacer(exprB.Parameters, exprA.Parameters).Visit(exprB.Body)),
                exprA.Parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(exprA.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(exprB.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(exprC.ToString());
        Func<int, bool> funcA = exprA.Compile();
        Func<int, bool> funcB = exprB.Compile();
        Func<int, bool> funcC = exprC.Compile();
        Debug.Assert(funcA(3) && !funcA(4) && !funcA(5));
        Debug.Assert(!funcB(3) && funcB(4) && !funcB(5));
        Debug.Assert(funcC(3) && funcC(4) && !funcC(5));
    }
}
```

Note that: `ExpressionParameterReplacer` is a helper class that you should put it in your helpers or anywhere accessible, and does not exists in standard packages.

```
public class ExpressionParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ExpressionParameterReplacer(IList<ParameterExpression> fromParameters, IList<ParameterExpression> toParameters)
    {
        ParameterReplacements = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
        for (int i = 0; i != fromParameters.Count && i != toParameters.Count; i++)
            ParameterReplacements.Add(fromParameters[i], toParameters[i]);
    }

    private IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> ParameterReplacements { get; set; }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        ParameterExpression replacement;
        if (ParameterReplacements.TryGetValue(node, out replacement))
            node = replacement;
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

---

### Sample in my own scenario

My normal usage of this was to add multiple conditions together in one of my services, which I do not have direct access to the Query so I cannot use multiple `.Where()` functions:

```
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> filter = w => ...;

// Extra complex filters which I do not feed to my request models
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> filter2 = null;
switch (model.PredefinedFilter)
{
    case OrderPredefinedFilterEnum.SupportPending:
        filter2 = w => 
            (
                (w.Cart.CartFlow == CartFlowEnum.Buyer_First_Order_Request && w.Cart.CartStatus == CartStatusEnum.PaidByBuyer) || 
                (w.Cart.CartFlow == CartFlowEnum.Seller_First_Suggestion && w.Cart.CartStatus == CartStatusEnum.WaitingForPaymentConfirmByBuyer)
            ) && 
            w.Cart.CartSupportStatus == CartSupportStatusEnum.Waiting;
        break;
}

if(filter2 != null)
{
    filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(filter.Body, new ExpressionParameterReplacer(filter2.Parameters, filter.Parameters).Visit(filter2.Body)), 
        filter.Parameters[0]);
}

result = (await _orderRepository.GetAllAsNoTrackingAsync(
    a => totalCount = a,
    filter,
    selector,
    OrderBy,
    take,
    skip,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken))
    .ToList();
```