# Combining two expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-6.0

I have an Expression<func<Portfolio, bool>> and I want to add an extra condition if an expression is true, here is my code,

```
Expression<Func<Portfolio, bool>> condition = x =>
        x.Client == Params.Client
        && x.AnalysisDate == Params.AnalysisDate
        && x.AsOf <= Params.ReportDate

    if (Params.Names.Any())
    {
        //Here I want to add an extra condition to add the following to the condition
       && portfoliosParams.Names.Contains(x.Name);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039753/how-to-add-another-condition-to-an-expression

Comment: since we know little about the types of your variables, please post an attempt how you want to apply the condition. Maybe it becomes clearer for you also

Comment: Is there a relation between `Params` and `portfoliosParams` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an Expression AND clause from two expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684010/how-to-create-an-expression-and-clause-from-two-expressions)

Comment: actually it would help us really to know the types of `portfoliosParams` and `Params` and the declaration of the `Portfolio` class

Answer (score 1):

If `Params.Names.Any()` (shouldn't it be `portfoliosParams.Names.Any()` ?) is evaluated before you build the expression, the easiest way to achieve this is probably like so :

```
Expression<Func<Portfolio, bool>> condition;

if (Params.Names.Any())
{
    condition = x => x.Client == Params.Client &&
                     x.AnalysisDate == Params.AnalysisDate &&
                     x.AsOf <= Params.ReportDate &&
                     portfoliosParams.Names.Contains(x.Name);
}
else
{
    condition = x => x.Client == Params.Client &&
                     x.AnalysisDate == Params.AnalysisDate &&
                     x.AsOf <= Params.ReportDate;
}
```

Otherwise you should include the condition in the expression:

```
Expression<Func<Portfolio, bool>> condition = x =>
    x.Client == Params.Client &&
    x.AnalysisDate == Params.AnalysisDate &&
    x.AsOf <= Params.ReportDate &&
    (Params.Names.Count() == 0 || portfoliosParams.Names.Contains(x.Name));
```

Finally is you really need to build up the expression, there is already [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684010) about expression combination.